# What is the need of Put method when all the things can be done in Post in Aspnet MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, http-post, http-put

In MVC **HttpPost** is used for creating a resource in the server and **HttpPut** is used for updating the existing resource in the server (if resource did not exist then create a new resource).

Let see the below model class.

```
public class Employee
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

To Create a fresh record in the database, I have created a HttpPost type action method in the controller and sent the employee object from view to controller with all the property values filled except for ID property.

As ID property is not present in the model I will execute the Create logic in the application.

Now, If I want to update this record then I can still use the same HttpPost method but this time value of ID is not null.

So, If I can do both "Update" and "Insert" from the same HttpPost method then what is the need of HttpPut.

Answer (score -1):

The main difference between POST and PUT methods of http stack is PUT is idempotent and POST is not. That means let's say you run a loop from client app and in each iteration you do PUT call to server. In this case the server will produce the same results. But if it is a POST, the server will produce multiple resources.